# Finding most important image on web page

Tags: php, parsing, dom, thumbnails

When a link is posted on Reddit, Facebook, and various other sites, it often includes a thumbnail of an image on the page.

How do sites like these find the most important or relevant image on the page, effectively ignoring site logos, banner ads, etc.?

Related:  [How major websites capture thumbnails from a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462044/how-major-websites-capture-thumbnails-from-a-link)

Comment: It has been asked *even earlier*, with plenty of precise answers :) e.g. [How can I take fullscreen screenshot of website](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1488589)

Comment: they all are about capturing screenschots of entire page, what I exactly wanted to know was..for ex: when somebody posts a pic from imgur.com in reddit, reddit picks only the pic and displays as thumbnail.

Comment: Ah, okay. Consider updating your question with that information

Comment: @Pekka, I re-wrote his question, and have voted to re-open, now that we know what she wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [parse the page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/362536), and look for a larger image.  There is no sure-fire way to determine the best image to use.

You might also consider filtering out ads by looking for anything with the text "ad" and what not.